# How to hide or disable the google logo, footer, copyright on google maps JavaScript API v3?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I have this assignment at work in which I need to use the Google maps API v3 and the design they gave me was without the logo/footer/copyright that google puts in the inferior part of the map.  Well, I need to have it disabled or hidden because I was told that I need to match the exact design no matter what.

I had to emphasize that by doing this I breach the terms of use of Google service...

> **9.4 Attribution.**
>
> > (a) Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features of Google, its partners, or other third party rights holders of content indexed by Google. When Google provides this attribution, you must display it as provided through the Service or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation and may not delete or in any manner alter these trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features.
> >     https://developers.google.com/maps/terms

Well at my work they didn't care about that and they always told me to do it anyway so these is how I'm doing it.

In the css I added the following lines of code:

```
#map-report div.gmnoprint,
#map-report div.gmnoscreen {
    display: none;      
}

img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/google_white.png"] {
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: per google api terms of use, you can't remove any of that stuff. if you do and they find out, at the very least they will ban your site/software from using there api. but they could do worse involving copyright claims. Although Im sure you can remove them after they are loaded into the DOM for those hard headed enough to try. I wouldn't advice it

Comment: You could use OpenLayers instead?

Comment: Try MapBox, I believe they have a licensing agreement that you can have those similar attributes removed

Comment: I know these is un-ethical, against the terms of service and all of these, I tried to explain these to my boss and never remove the logo but He said I had to do it, and I searched a lot and never found the way to do it.

Comment: Im going to agree with @josh3736 maybe its time for a new job, lets say hypothetically google goes after your company. Whats to say the boss man doesn't stick it to you, and you somehow end up having to suffer the consequences.

Comment: @barro32: Even though OpenLayers itself doesn't require attribution, the data source you use to get the maps that OpenLayers displays usually **does**.  For example, OSM [requires](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright) attribution.  PS: If you're going the open source route, [Leaflet](http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/) is *much* better than OpenLayers.

Comment: @chris No, they don't have such a license. MapBox uses OSM data and a different API.

Comment: Tell the designer to add the copyright in the design.

Comment: I am looking to remove the copyright notice with the intention of moving it to another place. Mapbox allows this (https://www.mapbox.com/help/remove-attribution/). What about Google?

Comment: Gajus, googles terms says "may not ... in any manner alter these ". You can't alter it. You could possibly request permission to move it to another place. If it's a huge concern, I'd use OSM (your own server)/leaflet/bing (satellite) and put all the attribution in a small container.

Comment: Do want you want, but considering that Google Maps is free. I wouldn't take advantage of a great service. You could your own platform I guess?

Comment: At least a smart move to leave something here to have prove you did not want to do that in the first place... :)

Comment: Sorry can't resist writing a comment to this even if i get downgraded. This question is freaking hilarious! "Please prosecute my company, I'm not going to be the scapegoat!"

Comment: This is old, but just a thought, because I have to do the same thing ... the TOS says you must DISPLAY them, it doesn't say anything about letting the users CLICK on them accidentally... so instead of putting the CSS in with "display:none;" why not use "pointer-events:none;"?  That will still show the items, but just not let people click on them.

Answer (score 140):

## This CSS works like charm [October 2019 tested]. 
Removes *Google Logo*, *terms of use*, and *Report a problem* div.

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}
a[href^="https://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}

.gmnoprint a, .gmnoprint span, .gm-style-cc {
    display:none;
}
.gmnoprint div {
    background:none !important;
}
```

Comment: May be worth adding: `a[title="Report problems with Street View imagery to Google"]` to hide the "Report a problem" div.

Comment: Unfortunately, it also removes the distance scale... Any idea how to preserve it?

Comment: I would recommend putting the Google logo there, without the link, at least to give some credit.

Comment: Still working in October 2016. Note that the last rule will remove background from visible elements such as "+", "-" buttons etc.

Comment: Be careful with this. As this is a ToS violation one day your domain might be blocked by Google.

Comment: @xomena haha may be, but how is google going to detect it? We are just hiding it. Unless Google crawl website and detect that.
Is it mentioned somewhere that we cannot hide that?

Comment: Sure read [ToS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) paragraph 9.4: "Content provided to you through the Service may contain the Brand Features of Google, its strategic partners, or other third-party rights holders of content that Google indexes. When Google provides those Brand Features or other attribution through the Service, you must display such attribution as provided (or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation) and must not delete or alter the attribution."

Comment: Search RefererDeniedMapError in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/), there are examples of people who was blocked.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you @AbhishekGoel

Comment: This also removes ruler and zoom controls

Comment: This is great, for me, I had to remove `.gmnoprint div` as it took away the white background behind the zoom controls.

Comment: Also a ToS related warning: If you're caught violating, Google team **WILL NOT FIX** the issue. Not until you send an appeal and is accepted.

Comment: Still Works August 2019

Answer (score 22):

Try this for api v3:

`.gm-style-cc { display:none; }`

Comment: This works but for the things that you see on the bottom right of the map. The Google logo is still there on the bottom left part. Anyway, good and thanks!!

Answer (score 15):

**Jan 2018 update**. Leaves only clean map:

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"],
a[href^="https://maps.google.com/maps"],
a[href^="https://www.google.com/maps"] {
    display: none !important;
}
.gm-bundled-control .gmnoprint {
    display: block;
}
.gmnoprint:not(.gm-bundled-control) {
    display: none;
}
```

**As of Feb 2018 the CSS above makes markers on the map unclickabe**. If you don't have any markers you shoudn't have any problems, but if you do just remove the last CSS rule `.gmnoprint:not(.gm-bundled-control)`, the markers will become clickable but there will be some little copyright and terms of use labels

Comment: "dirt"? Do you have any idea how much effort Google has put into offering these maps for free?

Comment: are not free my friend.

Answer (score 9):

As you mentioned, removing the Google logo and copyright notices **is not compliant with the [Google Maps APIs TOS](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)**, specifically with paragraph 9.4:

*"Content provided to you through the Service may contain the Brand Features of Google, its strategic partners, or other third-party rights holders of content that Google indexes. When Google provides those Brand Features or other attribution through the Service, you must display such attribution as provided (or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation) and must not delete or alter the attribution."*.

To be compliant with Terms of Service please always make sure the Google logo and copyright notices are visible.

Comment: Just to clarify, visible means they have to be somewhere visible on the page, or within the actual Google Maps container? Because it can be useful to keep the Map cleaner to move the logo and copyright notice to a different spot.

Comment: Not an answer to the question (and the OP is clear they understand the breach of the TOS). Would be better as a comment.

Comment: Aug 2022 update!
(b) Attribution.  Customer will display all attribution that (i) Google provides through the Services (including branding, logos, and copyright and trademark notices); or (ii) is specified in the Maps Service Specific Terms. Customer will not modify, obscure, or delete such attribution.

Answer (score 7):

Works like a charm with v3:

```
.gm-style-cc {
  display: none !important;
}

.gm-style a[href^="https://maps.google.com/maps"] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Take a note for 2nd selector I use `.gm-style` before `a` because otherwise it will hide *all* links to `https://maps.google.com/maps` not only from google map itself.

Answer (score 5):

You can't remove it from API. But you can use a div which you can place on the copyright notice

```
<div style="width:100px; height:15px; position:absolute; margin-left:100px margin-

bottom:50px; background-color:white;">
</div>
```

do the changes to height,width and margins according to need.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```css
#map-report a img { display:none; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can prevent the click on google copyright.so, that it will not let user to move out of your applicaiton.Hope this resolves your problem.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
    // do something only the first time the map is loaded
    //@mapCopyright - gets the google copyright tags
    var mapCopyright=document.getElementById('map-canvas').getElementsByTagName("a");   
        $(mapCopyright).click(function(){
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

First put your maps in a container :

```
<div id="map">
    <div class="google-maps"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden; //important
}
#map .google-maps {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 110%;  //that will do the trick
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm loving the logic, little bit hacky though.

Answer (score 2):

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"],a[href^="https://maps.google.com/maps"] {
     display: none !important;
}
.gmnoprint a,.gmnoprint span,.gm-style-cc { 
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Please put your answer always in context instead of just pasting code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

use this code(css)

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"]{display:none !important}
```

Answer (score 1):

this:

```
#map-repor > div { 
  height: 105% !important;
}
```

is enough in my case

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
$('#map span:contains("©")')
    .closest('.gmnoprint')
    .css('opacity', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Improving on another solution here, this just disables the links in the map, so people don't leave the app (and get stuck without a way to go back). On an app it makes a big difference when people try to scroll a small map and tap by mistake.

```
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){

      $("#map a").click(function(){
          return false;
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for now, at least until they modify the title attribute for the link around the logo.

```
.gm-style a[title='Click to see this area on Google Maps']{ display: none!important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.gm-style > div:first-child {
z-index: 10000000 !important;
}
```

z-index: 1000000 is added by js for all divs, but we want see only map, so we must set z-index to 10000000

Comment: Too aggressive: it kills also e.g. streetview.

Answer (score 0):

### One-liners working with V3

#### CSS

```
#map .gm-style > div:not(:first-child) { display: none; }
```

#### jQuery

```
$('#map .gm-style > div:not(:first-child)').remove()
```

Comment: without jQuery : 

`document.querySelectorAll('#map .gm-style > div:not(:first-child)').forEach((el) => { el.remove() });`

Answer (score 0):

```
  .gm-style-mtc,
  .gm-svpc,
  .gm-style-cc {
    display: none;
  }
```

i think you should add a wrapper block to change new style! and with Google logo on the left footer. you can use inspect element to get ours selector same here.

```
#example-map > div > div > div:nth-child(3) {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google map Version 3:

Hide google logo:

```
a[href^="http://maps.google.com/maps"],
a[href^="https://maps.google.com/maps"],
a[href^="https://www.google.com/maps"],
```

Hide terms:

```
.gm-style-cc { 
    display:none !important
}
```